# Rectifier for a resistive heater

Tags: power, power-electronics

I want to know how can I heat a plate at 2KW using an electrical circuit. I need this circuit for a research project. I have to heat a large area so I am hoping that I could use something like a wire mesh to heat the plate.

I was looking to directly supply 220V AC to a resistive wire, but my advisor says it might be dangerous to do so.

I would be grateful if you could help me out with the circuit.

Plate Dimensions: 400mm x 64mm base area.

Comment: Why do you want to rectify it? It doesn't make it any less dangerous...

Comment: Use some large incandescent light bulbs.

Comment: Are you sure there is no off-the-shelf froducts like you need?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the plate is not in an open space to put large incandescent light bulbs

Comment: I'll second analogsystemsrf's idea. A quick google shows that a 250 W heat lamp is fairly standard. Use 8 of those and you've got 2 kW of heat without messing around with resistance wire.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum there are heating elements used in water heaters, but they are small for my application.

Comment: 2KW does not mean anything here without dimensions, temperatures required, space limitations etc. Also, rectifying makes no sense....

Comment: @Trevor temperature is not important to me. I need to heat the plate at 2KW to observe a good result for my study.

Comment: Break open a few kettles to get the heaters.

Comment: There are all kinds of heater elements out there... for example http://www.asbheat.com/products#tubular-heaters Or if it's a quick and dirty, go find an appliance repair shop and jury-rig a clothes drier heater element with a suitably rated dimmer.

Comment: You want to put 2 kW of heat into a 40 x 6.4 cm plate and you're worried about electrical safety? I'd be more worried about burning the building down. ;-)

Comment: @Andrew. Ditto. OP also needs to figure out how to actually transfer right amount of heat to plate vs elsewhere.

Comment: What temperature does it need to get to? If it's less than 100 °C you could have a bath of water at the correct temperature and pump water through the block. You should be able to achieve 2 kW of heat transfer safely that way.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like what you need is a custom shape electric stove element.

Stove elements are typically directly connected to 220 VAC, but note that the resistive wire is encased in an electrical insulator (but thermal conductor) and then enclosed in a protective metal tube. This isolates the outer surface of the heating element from the electricity, making it safe (electrically at least).